# Turn monitors off on Windows 10 on Remote Desktop Connection

Tags: windows, windows-10, multiple-monitors, remote-desktop, display-settings

I am looking to disable my two monitors and turn them off once I connect to my Windows 10 Machine over remote desktop, if I walk out of the office and leave my machine on for remote access, the two monitors can use unnecessary power. Is there a way to have Windows disable the monitors rather than turning off the monitors manually?

Comment: Can’t you just turn the monitors off manually?  However, f you leave them on in a low power state, they will awake and show the lock screen.  However, later after the designated amount of time, they would go back to sleep mode.  If you manually turn them off you prevent this behavior.

Comment: @Nathaniel Suchy does the target computer not put the monitors into standby mode after the timeout period already defined in your power settings?

Comment: Can you use: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html in some way? `nircmd.exe monitor off`

Answer (score 7):

1. Open the `Power & sleep` settings menu: <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>O</kbd>
2. Set the `Screen` times to something practical.

[image]

- The target PC's monitors will enter standby mode after the timeout period has elapsed.
- The monitors will stay in standby mode while you are remotely connected to the PC via Remote Desktop.

Answer (score 1):

I have quite similar needs and I managed to find a working Solution. It’s not a perfect solution but rather a workaround. But it works fairly well for myself. I am using this solution on Windows 11 Enterprise 21H2 but it should works on any Windows 10 / 11 Pro / Enterprise / LTSC System. (Windows 10 / 11 Home version can NOT use this way, however)

My case: I have a Windows 11 desktop PC. It's connected to a monitor. But most of the time I am using it as a 7x24 running headless server. I am running several Hyper-V virtual machines on it and mainly operate / maintenance the PC remotely from RDP (Remote Desktop) session. However, some times I also use this PC locally to play video games. I want the PC’s monitor being off when (and ONLY when) I am not using it locally. And I do NOT want to turn on / off the power button of monitor manually every time.

In Windows Power Plan settings (Start Menu - type “power plan” - Edit power plan), you can config the “Turn off the display” settings (on battery / plugged in) to automatically turn off the monitor after certain times of inactivity. It only counts your local (none-RDP) session keyboard / mouse usage as activity. You can only set these values to as low as 1 minute in UI.

However, you can actually set these values to as low as 1 second using [Group Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/hh831791(v=ws.11)) (Win + R and run “gpedit.msc” to open Group Policy Editor). The corresponding config items is located in Computer Configuration \ Administrative Templates \ System \ Power Management \ Video and Display Settings - "Turn off the display (plugged in) (seconds)” and “Turn off the display (on battery)”. If configured, these Group Policy values will override the corresponding ones in Power Plan settings UI.

So in short, that’s my way: Automatically (programmatically) set these Group Policy values to “5 seconds” when I am not using the PC locally so it will (quickly) turn off the monitor; (Also automatically) Remove the “5 seconds” settings when I start using the PC locally so the monitor will not be turned off.

To programmatically modify the Group Policy config, I am using PowerShell and the [GroupPolicy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/grouppolicy/?view=windowsserver2019-ps) module. In start menu, type “powershell”, right click the “Windows PowerShell” and select “Run as administrator”, in the opened PS shell, paste and run the following 2 lines:

```
Install-Module -Name PolicyFileEditor -RequiredVersion 3.0.0
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass
```

The first line will download and install the “GroupPolicy” PS module from Microsoft server. The second line will change the [execution policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy?view=powershell-7.3) of PowerShell to (permanently) remove the restrictions of executing of unsigned PS scripts on this PC.

Now you can use PowerShell to modify group policy values. I wrote the following two PS scripts:

EnableMonitorAutoOff.ps1 : enable the monitor being turned off after 5 seconds of inactivity.

```
Import-Module -name "PolicyFileEditor"

# need to install PolicyFileEditor module
# https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PolicyFileEditor/3.0.0
#   Install-Module -Name PolicyFileEditor -RequiredVersion 3.0.0

Set-PolicyFileEntry -Path "$env:windir\system32\GroupPolicy\Machine\Registry.pol" -Key 'Software\Policies\Microsoft\Power\PowerSettings\3C0BC021-C8A8-4E07-A973-6B14CBCB2B7E' -ValueName 'ACSettingIndex' -Data 5 -Type 'DWord'

Set-PolicyFileEntry -Path "$env:windir\system32\GroupPolicy\Machine\Registry.pol" -Key 'Software\Policies\Microsoft\Power\PowerSettings\3C0BC021-C8A8-4E07-A973-6B14CBCB2B7E' -ValueName 'DCSettingIndex' -Data 5 -Type 'DWord'
```

DisableMonitorAutoOff.ps1: disable (remove) the “5 seconds inactivity monitor off” settings.

```
Import-Module -name "PolicyFileEditor"

# need to install PolicyFileEditor module
# https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PolicyFileEditor/3.0.0
#   Install-Module -Name PolicyFileEditor -RequiredVersion 3.0.0

Remove-PolicyFileEntry -Path "$env:windir\system32\GroupPolicy\Machine\Registry.pol" -Key 'Software\Policies\Microsoft\Power\PowerSettings\3C0BC021-C8A8-4E07-A973-6B14CBCB2B7E' -ValueName 'ACSettingIndex'

Remove-PolicyFileEntry -Path "$env:windir\system32\GroupPolicy\Machine\Registry.pol" -Key 'Software\Policies\Microsoft\Power\PowerSettings\3C0BC021-C8A8-4E07-A973-6B14CBCB2B7E' -ValueName 'DCSettingIndex'
```

To execute these (*.ps1) PowerShell scripts, I wrote the following two corresponding wrapper bat script:

EnableMonitorAutoOff.bat

```
@echo off

setlocal
cd /d %~dp0

powershell ./EnableMonitorAutoOff.ps1
timeout /t 1
gpupdate /Target:Computer /Force
```

DisableMonitorAutoOff.bat

```
@echo off

setlocal
cd /d %~dp0

powershell ./DisableMonitorAutoOff.ps1
timeout /t 1
gpupdate /Target:Computer /Force
```

The bat script will execute the corresponding PS script to modify the Group Policy, and call [gpupdate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/gpupdate) to make the changes take effect immediately. Just put these *.ps1 and *.bat files in (the same) any directory.

Finally, I use the Windows Task Scheduler (Win+R and run “taskschd.msc”) to add the following two triggered tasks to automatically disable / enable the “5 seconds inactivity monitor off” settings after I start / stop using the PC locally.

- OnLocalSessionConnected task properties

  - General: Check “Run whether user is logged or not”; Check “Run with highest privileges”
  - Triggers: On connection to user session: On local connection to any user session
  - Actions: Start a program: <path>/DisableMonitorAutoOff.bat
- OnLocalSessionDisonnected task properties

  - General: Check “Run whether user is logged or not”; Check “Run with highest privileges”
  - Triggers: On disconnect to user session: On local disconnect from any user session
  - Actions: Start a program: <path>/EnableMonitorAutoOff.bat

That’s done.

Last but not least. Now when you start using the PC locally (login physically), the OnLocalSessionConnected task will be triggered to remove the “5 seconds inactivity monitor off” settings. However, when you stop using the PC locally, you can’t just use Win + L to lock the screen. The Win + L  will only lock the screen, but will not disconnect local session (And unfortunately, I haven’t found any way to use the lock screen event as trigger in Task Scheduler). Instead, you should type Win + R and run “[tsdiscon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/tsdiscon)”. The “tsdiscon” command will still show the lock screen, but at the same time will also disconnect the current local session so the OnLocalSessionDisonnected task will be triggered to impose the “5 seconds inactivity monitor off” settings again. Next time you want to use the PC locally, just shake the mouse to wake up the monitor.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that there is any built-in way to do that, but the power options for the monitor will work. When you use RDP it's basically like having the machine locked, the monitors will work with the default time out (set in power settings) not with the built-in 60 second timeout when you lock the machine.

I have two 27" monitors that are really bright. So I wrote some scripts to change the monitor's sleep time for me.

```
@echo off

:: This script (Streen 1 Min.bat) will set the monitor timeout to "1 
   Minute" when run.
:: I did this because the monitors I have very bright.
:: The timeout for DC power source will be unchanged.

cls
powercfg /change monitor-timeout-ac 1
exit
```

If you want to get fancy, you can have Task Scheduler trigger the script based on a remote desktop event. You can make another one with whatever timeout period you usually use.

Also, if the screen has already been on for > 60 seconds, and you run the script, the monitor(s) will automatically go back to sleep.

Answer (score 0):

Connect the monitor to a smart switch which you can access remotely using your phone.